# Adding custom data to User Profile in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm working on small Symfony project. Besides everything it contains User authorization and profile. I added FOSUserBundle for this needs, it works great from the box btw.

Here is my `show_content.html.twig`, actually it's almost the same as it goes from the box:

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

<div class="fos_user_user_show">
    <p>{{ 'profile.show.email'|trans }}: {{ user.email }}</p>
    <p>{{ 'profile.show.points'|trans }}: {{ user.points }}</p>
    <p><a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}">Logout</a></p>
</div>
```

Each user can earn points. I created simple entity for it:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;    
     /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user_points")
     */
    class Points
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string")
         */
        protected $datetime;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        protected $points;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string")
         */
        protected $email;

        //Getters and setters go here
    }
```

I also added a simple form where a user can press a button and randomly generated points goes to his account. It worked well, as it was just was one more variable in a User entity. But now I need to implement points getting history in a user profile. This why Points entity was created. I see points are running to fos_user_points table, but how do I put this content to the User profile? I'm not sure if it's safe to directly grab 'em from a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it well, the Points are related to the User that created them. To implement this, you should create a one-to-many relation from your User entity to the Points entity. First you should write your own User entity that inherits from the one provided by FOSUserBundle.

For example:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Points")
     */
    protected $points;
```

By the way, what is the usage of the `email` attribute in the `Points` entity ? I f it was there to handle the relation between points and user, it isn't necessary anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I took a bit another way to implement what I want. I have overrode `showAction()` from **ProfileController**, and just have added `points` as variable to `$this->render` array. 
But now I'm stuck on writing `getPoints` function in Points class. How do you think will it work? or better use what you offered?

Comment: Glad to know that it works. But I still think you should implement the relationship between User and Points in the model, IMHO that would be more robust, more simple and easier to maintain. You would have a `points` property in the `User` class and a `user` property in the `Points`class. For a detailed explanation, see the part about [Entity Relationships/Associations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations) in the Symfony book.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely would try you solution

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just solved my problem this way:

I have overrode `showAction()` from *ProfileController.php* like this:

```
public function showAction()
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $points = $em->getRepository('AcmeUserBundle:Points')->findBy(array('email' => $user->getEmail()));
        if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
        }

        return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Profile:show.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
            'points' => $points
        ));
    }
```

and *show_content.html.twig* like this:

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

<div class="fos_user_user_show">
    <p>{{ 'profile.show.email'|trans }}: {{ user.email }}</p>
    <p>{{ 'profile.show.points'|trans }}: {{ user.points }}</p>
    <p>Points history:</p>
    <table style="border: 1px">
        {% for point in points %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ point.datetime }}</td>
                <td>{{ point.points }} points</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <p><a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}">Logout</a></p>
</div>
```

And now it works!

Comment: Actually, you can remove `!is_object($user)`